# Is GNU make wildcard able to match more complex patterns, like a regexp for example?

Tags: regex, linux, find, wildcard, gnu-make

Let's say I have the following wildcard matches in a makefile:

```
data-files = $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.png) \
    $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.gif) \
    $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.bmp) \
    $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.jpg) \
    $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.ico) \
    $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.dist) \
    $(wildcard $(ptdf)/*.html)
```

Can the wildcard syntax give me the power to match, for example, file names containing from 1 to 2 letters, as the regexp `\w{1,2}` would do? With no filename extension?

If not, how can I do that with other syntax with linux command (such as `find`, etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downloading the [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/) and grepping for `wildcard`, we find the definition of the function on [line 1332 of function.c](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/make/function.c?annotate=1.134&root=make#l1333)—`wildcard` calls `string_glob`, which just does [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), not regular expressions. And grepping the source code for `regex` turns up nothing :/

Since make has no built-in regex function, we'll have to use an external command. grepping for `regex` on the [find(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) shows that the following will work:

```
data-files = $(shell find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.\w{1,2}')
```

Comment: Just to clarify even more for seekers: This one is exactly what did the job: find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/\w{1,2}' It matches the files with one or two \w characters only, with no extension, in the current directory

Comment: I really like the habit of **looking inside free software's source code**. I find that a lot of newbies are not using the freedom given by free software.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch: When you say 'newbie', you should know, that I am software developer for at least 10+ years, and I accept your point only because I am into GNU / C++ stuff so recently. So yes, I am newbie in these. But what if? I just want the job done for now. Nothing else. The question is relevant and the answer is superb, what'ss the point of making 'parties' qualification?

Comment: I just say that you could have limited your comment to the habit of looking inside free software's source code, and skip the 'newbie' part.